# Error in the comp.lang.c FAQ? Calculating the length of a variadically formatted string

Tags: c, string, variadic-functions, strlen

Question 15.4: [varargs/varargs1.html](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html)

In the example code there, they seem to think ‍‍‍`va_arg` returns `NULL` if the end of the list has been reached:

```
len = strlen(first);

va_start(argp, first);

while((p = va_arg(argp, char *)) != NULL)
    len += strlen(p);

va_end(argp);
```

But the documentation for `va_arg` explicitly says this is not the case, and that `va_arg` will happily go past the end of the list.

This agrees with my experience trying to imitate the above code and getting a segfault as a result.

Comment: -1 for not reading the full article

Comment: I see, makes sense.  Everytime I learn something new about C, once I stop resisting, the beauty of the language increases even more

Comment: A comment for anybody who stumbles on this thread in the future:  if you want to automatically have the NULL added (assuming you are using CPP as your compiler) you can do it with a macro like so:  `#define myformatter(first,...) myformatter_(first, ## __VA_ARGS__, NULL)`

Comment: The `NULL` should be cast.  Please re-read the FAQ entry, and note the sentence which immediately follows the bit that everyone has quoted in their answers.  It explicitly draws attention to the cast and links to an explanation of why it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `va_arg` doesn't mention returning `NULL` at the nd of the list.

> If there is no next argument, or if
>   type is not compatible with the type
>   of the actual next argument (as
>   promoted according to the default
>   argument promotions), random errors
>   will occur.

But the FAQ says:

> A call to vstrcat looks something like
>
> ```
> char *str = vstrcat("Hello, ", "world!", (char *)NULL);
> ```

Which means they assume the caller will pass `NULL` as the last argument to **signal the end of the list**.

Answer (score 2):

They're passing a NULL pointer in the call to vstrcat().

```
A call to vstrcat looks something like

    char *str = vstrcat("Hello, ", "world!", (char *)NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note how `vstrcat`, in [the c-faq article](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html), is called:

```
char *str = vstrcat("Hello, ", "world!", (char *)NULL);
```

The last parameter is NULL. That's what va_arg returns